# Using UTF8 inside \path from the url package

Tags: unicode, urls

Whereas there are certain rules for how a URL is to be formed (where non ascii letters are not really allowed). How about `\path`? I happend to try `\path{æøå}`, saved in `latin1` this gives the expected result, whereas in `utf8` it gives six letters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % remember to convert file into latin1
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\path{æåø}

\texttt{æåø}
\end{document}
```

Comment: url.sty has the comment `% lots more to add, but I should later link into inputenc` which translates as: this doesn't work yet....

Comment: No problem, just wanted to be sure and make sure it was in the archive

Comment: I was going to add a fix but got pulled away and when I looked it's a bit tricky:-) You could just ask Donald to fix his package:-)

Comment: Or at least note it in the manual.

Comment: You know that you can compile with `xelatex`, dont you? XeTeX natively supports uft8, so you don't need (remove it) inputenc package.

Comment: As `pdflatex` is the most commenly used engine, that it what I use.